# Calling JavaScript variable in separate JQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use the value of a variable I define using JavaScript for a JQuery function. All of this happens in one .html file. In the body, I create this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var clicks = 1;
function onClick() {
    //Code here to change value of 'clicks'
};
</script>
```

Later in that file, I use JQuery to pull data from a server when a button called 'previous' is clicked. I use this code:

```
$('#previous').click(function(){
    $('#question').load('/php/getQuestion.php',
      { name: $("clicks").val()} ); //This line is wrong
}
```

How can I insert the value of 'clicks' into the 'name' field? Thanks

Comment: Need HTML, because it isn't obvious what `"clicks"` actually is supposed to be. 1. If a selector is wrapped in quotes `$("tag")` it's a `<tag>`,  2. if a selector is wrapped in quotes and is prtefixed with a period: `$(".class")` 3. If a selector is wrapped in quotes and is prefixed with a hashmark: `$('#id')`. `$("clicks")` means: *find any `<clicks>` elements. Of course that element doesn't even exist has the root of your problem.

Comment: If both of those blocks are within scope, then you have the real number 1 as a jQuery object which is invalid I think you'll get a type error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`clicks` is a global variable, so you can use it directly:

```
$('#previous').click(function(){
    $('#question').load('/php/getQuestion.php',
      { name: clicks} );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`$("clicks")` is looking for  a form control element `<clicks></clicks>` that clearly doesn't exist and certainly wouldn't have a `value`.

You simply need to use the variable:

```
 $('#question').load('/php/getQuestion.php', { name: clicks} );
```